# how to set some properties not xml element

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

In Java , I add `@XmlRootElement(name = "MyClass")` to my class , it let all properties in the class become xml elements , now I have one property ,it doesn't need to be xml element , what can I do ? Thank you. George

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "MyClass")
public class MyClass{
    public String A ;
    public String B ;

    //what xml anotation to be set here ?
    public String notXmlelement ; 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a field which should not be persisted as XML (I assume you are using JAXB), then mark it as `@XmlTransient`.

```
@XmlTransient
public String notXmlelement;
```

Comment: +1 - There is also a way to do this using `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)`.  Useful if you are excluding more than half of the mapped fields/properties:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21786376/383861

Answer (score 1):

### Excluding Less than Half of Properties

If you are excluding less than half of the mapped fields/properties then you can do this using `@XmlTransient`.

```
public Class {

    public String a;   // include
    public String b;   // include
    public String c;   // include
    @XmlTransient public String d;   // exclude

}
```

### Excluding More than Half of Properties

If you are excluding more than half of the mapped fields/properties then you can specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` and then only annotated fields/properties will be included.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public Class {

    public String a;   // exclude
    public String b;   // exclude
    public String c;   // exclude
    @XmlElement public String d;   // include

}
```

### For More Information

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html